# Is "Where In" querying like in Sql Server possible in DocumentDB?

Tags: c#, azure-cosmosdb

I have this following simple Sql Where In that I am trying in DocumentDB but am not able to make it work on the Query Explorer:

```
SELECT * FROM root.DocumentDbTest_AllFieldTypes f
    WHERE f.field1 NOT IN (
                            SELECT g.field1 FROM root.DocumentDbTest_AllFieldTypes g 
                            WHERE g.time = "09:12:34"
                          );
```

I am getting this following error:
[image: Syntax error, incorrect syntax near 'SELECT'.]

Can someone please tell me the correct syntax perhaps for doing this IN query?

Comment: here is the tutorial, maybe it will help https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/documentdb-sql-query/

Comment: do you need the `in` clause for this query?

Comment: What you are doing is a relational JOIN. DocumentDB provides an `IN` operator but only to check against a list of values, while you are trying to perform a JOIN between documents. This is *not* a typical scenario for a document database. In fact the JOIN operator supports only *intra-document* joins, ie joins inside the same document to extract child nodes.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos (one!) real example - I have some tables Developers, Managers, and Mentors which are joined in a third table DevManagers and DevMentors and ManagerMentorControl by their Ids using 1-to-many from managers/mentors to the devs/metors. Now for some lookup on some protected table data (by security logic) I have to check if a Manager has access to the Devs and Mentors and Mentors have access to the Devs before allowing the managers to do the lookup on that third table. And I cannot include diff types in one for business reasons. I expected DocDb is MS so it might be possible :) :(

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, sorry, forgot to add point - the DevManagers and DevMentors are actually Role groups and not individual users.

Answer (score 1):

Document supports the `IN` operator in `WHERE` clauses; but it does not support subselects.

In other words... this is supported:

```sql
SELECT food.id,
       food.description,
       food.tags,
       food.foodGroup,
       food.version
FROM food
WHERE food.foodGroup IN ("Poultry Products",
                         "Sausages and Luncheon Meats")
```

This is not supported:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM root.DocumentDbTest_AllFieldTypes f
WHERE f.field1 NOT IN
    ( SELECT g.field1
     FROM root.DocumentDbTest_AllFieldTypes g
     WHERE g.time = "09:12:34" );
```

If you'd like to see subselects in DocumentDB, please voice your opinion by voting for this feature on [DocumentDB's feedback page](http://feedback.azure.com/forums/263030-documentdb).

Comment: hey @aliuy thanks for your reply - I was afraid of this answer.
This limitation actually makes it quite hard (neigh impossible!!) then to implement DocDB in our business scenario..... :(

Comment: @Deb on the contrary - in fact document (or document-like) databases are being used in business for *decades*. Just think SharePoint. It's a *different* model, requiring a *different* design. One could argue that it's easier to represent an *order* as a document rather than separate header and line tables